# jQuery UI, droppable , accept maximum number of elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

is there any way to set the maximum elements the drop target can accept ?

and is there any standard way to list all the dropped items ??

thanks

Comment: what do you mean by *list* the items? [rearrange](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#photo-manager) them after dropping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a counter on the `drop` event to disable the droppable when the limit is reached:

```
$(function() {
    var limit = 5;
    var counter = 0;
    $('.drag').draggable({revert: "invalid"});
    $('.drop').droppable({
        drop: function() {
            counter++;
            if (counter == limit) {
                alert('limit reached!');
                $(this).droppable("disable");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[Example link](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/DVgG8/). Please note that this is only a demo, you may probably need to use `accept` and `scope` options.

Comment: fails if we move dropped boxes, any suggestion ?